# Programmatically simulate a shipping rate request for a specific weight (for testing purposes)

Tags: shipping, shipping-address, testing

**How can I more quickly test different shipping scenarios?**

I have a client that is asking for some changes to some [already] very complex shipping logic. We are using a module to "override" the shipping methods' availability and price.

I have been testing each weight class manually, by adjusting the quantity of a product to get my cart to have a specific total weight.

In theory, I should be able to make a utility that shows me each outcome on a single page, but so far all my attempts have failed.

**I have already tried to:**

1. Set the weight on a pre-existing quote object, then collect the rates.

   ```
   $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
   $address->setWeight($my_custom_weight)->collectShippingRates();
   ```

   This does not work because collectShippingRates re-collects the product weights before actually summing everything up.
2. I have also tried to create my own `shipping/rate_request` object, and call `Mage::getModel('shipping/shipping')->collectRates($request);`.

   This won't work for me because the override rules are applied by an overridden `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Rate` class, which never gets called unless you request the rates through the address model.
3. I have tried to programmatically modify my quote such that the product quantity gives me the desired weight (for example, I have a product that weighs 1lb, I want to "test" 10lb, so it sets the qty to 10, saves the quote, then requests the shipping rates.) This seems to work at first, but not when I try to do it 4 times in a row. Each subsequent request pulls the rates from the `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` table, showing the same rates as the first test.
4. Last resort (haven't tried yet) is to create 4 separate carts/quotes, then loading the quote by ID to get the shipping options. I really don't like this solution because it isn't very reusable.

Background: To create the logic initially, I opened 3 browser windows (Firefox + Chrome + Incognito) in order to have 3 different carts (with 3 different weights.) This made it very easy to test and make sure that all 3 weight classes work as specified by the client.
Previously there were 3 weight classes, but now there are 4, each with different available methods/pricing overrides/markups.
Now that they have a 4th weight class, it seems like I should find a more efficient way of doing this.